# Like Button Width Not Working - Causes Browser Horizontal Scrolling

Tags: css, facebook, facebook-like

I have two instances of where the Like Button is not "listening" to the width I specify in the XFBML code.

It LOOKS fine, but something is mysteriously causing the like button to be extra wide and force the browser to do horizontal page scrolling even though the entire like button is within the page.

Example:
[EXAMPLE REMOVED] - see the sidebar.  I have to set the entire BODY to ignore overflow-x.  If not, the like button causes a ton of extra pixels out there (but I can't see them with Firebug).  I know this is the problem because if I remove it, then it looks fine.

Example 2:
[Screenshot of Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HncMA.png) - In the header, I had to move the margin over so far to the left, and I wanted it to be in the top-right corner.  Play with the CSS for fbheader in firebug and you'll see.

The code I'm using there:

```
<div class="fbheader">
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 FB.init({appId: 'your app id', status: true, cookie: true,
         xfbml: true});
};
(function() {
var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
e.src = document.location.protocol +
  '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
```

```
 <fb:like href="http://www.example.com" send="true" width="300" show_faces="false" font="arial" colorscheme="dark"></fb:like>
</div> <!--// End fbheader -->
```

Any ideas why this is happening??  Can anyone help?  It seems like a bug with the XFBML.

Comment: Can you show us screenshot of your problem?

Comment: Sorry, linking to <strike>spammy</strike> external websites isn't allowed.  You can represent your issue with images or create a prototype that demonstrates your issues.

Comment: OK, now I'm having the problem again. I  started using Asynch code and am calling it only in the header.  This is very intermittent which is causing problems for me.

Here is a non-spammy screenshot.


[non-spammy-screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/Ve7os.png)

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the buttons being very wide or incomplete?

Comment: The buttons AREN'T wide is the problem.  It looks like it should fit.  But something in this new call is making the browser scrollbar show up because something down there is extra wide.  I've replicated this on another site.  I'm using the async call used here:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Comment: Ok...how about doing a repro on a simple page that is unbranded and doesn't trigger the community spam sniffer dogs. Folks are just seeing these these products (whether on a website or in a screenshot) are and being annoyed by them. Also reducing this to a simple reproducible example is much easier for others to swallow rather than having to deal with the page + umpteen CSS and javascript files. Otherwise this question will continue to attract more downvotes and flags. Also have a read of this:  http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: CHILDREN:  I found a bug with your API and I politely asked for help in a technical manner.  I am not using your little forum to build backlinks to my site, which does happen to be well-respected in its community (whether or not you care about that means jack squat to me).

I am merely asking for assistance on something that is not my site's fault.  I shouldn't have to build you a new page when all you need to do is push the F12 key and see the problem is on YOUR end -- not mine. Fix it.

Good God. Deal with the fact that people make websites to sell products and that your code is NOT perfect.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, but none of the suggestions above worked for me. 
I found another solutions that did work, see http://britishinside.com/archive/2011/07/07/Facebook-Like-Button-Bug.aspx

Simply include this in your stylesheet:

```
#fb-root > div { left:0 }
```

Comment: Thanks! I was experiencing the exact same problem and I can confirm that this works for me. But note that you forgot the first character of the declaration. It should be "#fb-root", not "fb-root".

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug with facebook. Why don't you just update your fbheader class as follows:

```
.fbheader {
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

That should solve your issue ..

Good luck..

Comment: Thanks for the actual attempt at helping - unfortunately that didn't work in fixing Facebook's bug.  I also tried overflow-x:hidden; and the same thing shows up.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I found the problem was to do with a bug in Facebook's reset div. I fixed it like this:

```
#fb_like .fb_reset {
    /* fix for Facebook bug which causes horizontal scrollbars in browser */
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue using `#fb-root { display: none; }`

Answer (score 0):

You could try alter the width of fbheader class in css file, or even better, the parent element.

Sometimes when we use internal elements that cause the parent to get wider, the horizontal scroll get visible.

Another tip is to reposition the button, or set the margins and padding narrow.

Comment: Thanks, but I have done that and it seems like a hack (plus it just doesn't work).  

I have the widget placed where the width should not be a factor (see screenshot link above).  I have already told the widget to have a width of 300px and it's going far beyond that.

The only way to completely stop this is to make overflow-x hidden, which isn't good for small resolution viewers.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to apply this to the parent  container:

```
.my-parent-wrapper {
    display: inline-block; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

skipping overflow rule will work too

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same problem, using an iFrame script from facebook for a double "share" and "like" button. I hadn't specified a width in pixels. Fixed it by getting a replacement script, but this type specifying a width of 120 pixels in the box provided.